# os_log, logging subsystem and objectiveC not compiling

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm working on a project that has swift and objectiveC. I'd like to use os_log, but can't figure it out.
I can get the log to work to the default log, but if I try to create a custom log then the compiler complains about not knowing about OSLog in my objC files

Here is the swift extension:

```
import os.log

 extension OSLog {
    private static var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!

     static let main = OSLog(subsystem: subsystem, category: "main")
}
```

In my objectiveC file I import the -Swift.h file and it can see other swift class I have, but still can't see OSLog.
`os_log_debug([OSLog main], "message");`

gets the following errors:
- Use of undeclared identifier 'Log'; did you mean 'log'?
- Bad receiver-type 'void (*)(id, ...)'

I'm clearly missing something ...

Comment: Did you find a solution to the above?

Comment: @Deepika, no I just moved on

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@objc` before `extension`:

```swift
@objc extension OSLog {
    private static var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!

    static let main = OSLog(subsystem: subsystem, category: "main")
}
```

Comment: I tried and the compiler complained about the static variables...`Static property cannot be in an @objc extension of a class (without @nonobjc) because class 'OSLog' is only visible via the Objective-C runtime`